# How to enable mySQLi on cPanel

Tags: php, mysqli, cpanel

I imported a php file (which connects with the website database) to cPanel.

I am getting an error in the line of "mysqli_stmt::get_result()"

I tried to add the extension of mySQLi via PHP selector and output the following code.

```
<?php
if (function_exists('mysqli')) {
    echo "Yes.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "No.<br />\n";
}

?>
```

It outputs 'No', unfortunately.

The below image shows the extensions I have enabled via PHP Selector.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Qxz.png)

If anyone has any suggestions at all how to install MySQLi into cPanel please be kind enough to mention as a comment or an answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: mysqli is not a function, so that test does nothing, what's your actual error?

Comment: "I am getting an error in the line of 'mysqli_stmt::get_result()'" Why don't you give us that error message?

Comment: Why no one uses the "[official](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php)" way to check for extensions I'll never know `extension_loaded('mysqli')`   try `dl('mysqli.so')`  I never tried this but just seen it when I was grabbing the link... lol  http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

Comment: and this got 4 up votes, i'm confused

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli` isn't a function, it's a class.

Try using `class_exists('mysqli')` instead.

Comment: try `extension_loaded('mysqli')`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Comment: Also `php -m` from command line

Comment: I only know `php -v` and `php -f` from the command line, sadly..  Oh and `php -h`

Comment: maybe `php -rc mysqli` nope that says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1` :-(  see I don't know that one.

Comment: You should also be familiar with php -r as well e.g.  `php -r "echo extension_loaded('mysqli')?'y':'n';"`

Comment: I only use `-f` to load a file for CRON, well sometimes I run a file.

Comment: I figured it out it's `--rc` and says `Exception: Class mysqli does not exist`  But I don't use Mysqli, so I turned it off, then I can say on SO, I cant test that because it uses Mysqli ... LOL